# Use a dataframe as a correspondance table

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a database that looks like:

```
> database
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    1    1
[2,]    2    2    3    4
[3,]    4    4    4    1
```

And a correspondance table, which is a dataframe:

```
> corresp
  number  name
1      1 name1
2      2 name2
3      3 name3
4      4 name4
```

How can I replace the numbers by the corresponding names in my database without using a loop?

(For replication:)

```
database <- rbind(c(1, 2, 1, 1), 
                  c(2, 2, 3, 4),
                  c(4, 4, 4, 1))
corresp <- data.frame(number = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                      name = c("name1","name2","name3","name4"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No loops, not even `apply`:

```
database[] <- as.character(corresp$name)[match(database, corresp$number)]

database
#     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   
#[1,] "name1" "name2" "name1" "name1"
#[2,] "name2" "name2" "name3" "name4"
#[3,] "name4" "name4" "name4" "name1"
```

Comment: was about to post the same ;-)

Comment: where can I find documentation for this [] notation?

Comment: @gpier I don't know, but if you use it the dimensions of the object with a dim attribute are kept.

Answer (score 3):

Using `apply` with `match`

```
apply(database,2,function(x) corresp$V2[match(x,corresp$V1)])
     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   
[1,] "name1" "name2" "name1" "name1"
[2,] "name2" "name2" "name3" "name4"
[3,] "name4" "name4" "name4" "name1"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `match` along with `apply` to replace all columns of `database` by their looked up names.

```
database <- data.frame(database, stringsAsFactors = F)
apply(database, 2, function(x) corresp$name[match(x,corresp$number)])

    X1      X2      X3      X4     
[1,] "name1" "name2" "name1" "name1"
[2,] "name2" "name2" "name3" "name4"
[3,] "name4" "name4" "name4" "name1"
```